# Running AOSP tests

Tags: android, android-source

I am trying to run some AOSP tests, but I can't run any test except for the cts. I mention that I am trying to do this with an emulator. This is the output from my terminal:

```
manuel@banstyle:~/aosp/development/testrunner$ ./runtest.py -v core
Building tests...
about to run adb  shell cat /data/local.prop
about to run adb  shell ls -l /data/local.prop
about to run adb  root
ONE_SHOT_MAKEFILE="frameworks/base/tests/CoreTests/Android.mk" make -j16 -C "/home/manuel/aosp" all_modules 
about to run adb  shell pm list instrumentation | grep android.core/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner
Error: adb  shell pm list instrumentation | grep android.core/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner returned 1 error code
Could not find instrumentation android.core/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner on device. Try forcing a rebuild by updating a source file, and re-executing runtest.
Exiting due to AbortError...
manuel@banstyle:~/aosp/development/testrunner$ ./runtest.py -v calculator
Building tests...
about to run adb  root
ONE_SHOT_MAKEFILE="packages/apps/Calculator/Android.mk" make -j16 -C "/home/manuel/aosp" all_modules 
adb push /home/manuel/aosp/out/target/product/generic/data/app/CalculatorTests.odex data/app/CalculatorTests.odex
about to run adb  push /home/manuel/aosp/out/target/product/generic/data/app/CalculatorTests.odex data/app/CalculatorTests.odex
adb install -r /home/manuel/aosp/out/target/product/generic/data/app/CalculatorTests.apk
about to run adb  install -r /home/manuel/aosp/out/target/product/generic/data/app/CalculatorTests.apk
32 KB/s (2699 bytes in 0.080s)
pkg: /data/local/tmp/CalculatorTests.apk
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_DEXOPT]

about to run adb  shell pm list instrumentation | grep com.android.calculator2.tests/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner
Error: adb  shell pm list instrumentation | grep com.android.calculator2.tests/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner returned 1 error code
Could not find instrumentation com.android.calculator2.tests/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner on device. Try forcing a rebuild by updating a source file, and re-executing runtest.
Exiting due to AbortError...
manuel@banstyle:~/aosp/development/testrunner$
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

I also have the same issue when I try 4.2.2. However, I don't have the problem when I work on 4.3. After googling, I realize the problem is caused by apk and odex. In 4.2.2, tests are compiled into apk and odex, which means, the apk doesn't contain the classes.dex. The odex file contains all classes. This actually cause the failure when you only "adb install apk", because pm cannot find the classes.dex.

The way to solve this is to add `LOCAL_DEX_PREOPT := false` in the Android.mk. This will put the dex back to the apk. I have tried this in 4.2.2 full-eng.

This thread also gives some info. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-building/OrBJsS2J3sw